# How to Resize D3 Line Charts

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a question about resizing D3 multi line charts. I followed [Building Responsive Visualizations with D3.js](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/blog/2014/02/17/building-responsible-visualizations-d3-js/). But I am having trouble updating the elements inside of my chart. I am successfully updating the axis, but not the lines themselves. I also am unsure of how to update the dots and text in the graph.

Thanks for your help!

Here is the code I have so far:

```
<svg id="graph"></svg>

<script>

// Set the dimensions of the canvas / graph
var margin = 40,
    width = 960 - margin*2,
    height = 500 - margin*2;


// Parse the date / time
var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d").parse;

// Set the ranges
var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]);
var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);

// Define the axes
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x)
.orient("bottom").ticks(5);

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y)
.orient("left").ticks(8);

// Define the line
var valueline = d3.svg.line()
.x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
.y(function(d) { return y(d.average_ticnum); });

var valueline2 = d3.svg.line()
.x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
.y(function(d) { return y(d.average_fatiguenum); });

var valueline3 = d3.svg.line()
.x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
.y(function(d) { return y(d.average_stressnum); });

var valueline4 = d3.svg.line()
.x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
.y(function(d) { return y(d.sum_nf_sugars); });

var valueline5 = d3.svg.line()
.x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
.y(function(d) { return y(d.sum_nf_total_carbohydrate); });

// Adds the svg canvas
var graph = d3.select("#graph")
    .attr("width", width + margin*2)
    .attr("height",  height + margin*2)
.append("g")
   .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin + "," + margin + ")");


// Get the data
d3.json("progress_output.php?useremail=<?php echo $useremail; ?>",     function(error, data) {
data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.date = parseDate(d.date);
    d.average_ticnum = +d.average_ticnum;
    d.fatiguenum = +d.average_fatiguenum;
    d.stressnum = +d.average_stressnum;
});

// Scale the range of the data
x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));
y.domain([0,12]);

// Add the valueline path.
graph.append("path")
.attr("class", "line")
.style("stroke", "#891f83")
.attr("id","ticLine")
.attr("d", valueline(data));

graph.append("path")
.attr("class", "line")
.style("stroke", "#7db6e3")
.attr("id","fatigueLine")
.attr("d", valueline2(data));

graph.append("path")
.attr("class", "line")
.style("stroke", "#36376a")
.attr("id","stressLine")
.attr("d", valueline3(data));

graph.append("path")
.attr("class", "line")
.style("stroke", "#9bcf81")
.attr("id","sugarLine")
.attr("d", valueline4(data));

graph.append("path")
.attr("class", "line")
.style("stroke", "#efa465")
.attr("id","carbLine")
.attr("d", valueline5(data));

// Add the Dots
graph.selectAll("dot")
.data(data)
.enter().append("circle")
.attr("id","ticDots")
.attr("r", 3.5)
.style("fill", "#891f83")
.attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d.date); })
.attr("cy", function(d) { return y(d.average_ticnum); });

graph.selectAll("dot")
.data(data)
.enter().append("circle")
.attr("r", 3.5)
.style("fill", "#7db6e3")
.attr("id","fatigueDots")
.attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d.date); })
.attr("cy", function(d) { return y(d.average_fatiguenum); });

graph.selectAll("dot")
.data(data)
.enter().append("circle")
.attr("r", 3.5)
.style("fill", "#36376a")
.attr("id", "stressDots")
.attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d.date); })
.attr("cy", function(d) { return y(d.average_stressnum); });

graph.selectAll("dot")
.data(data)
.enter().append("circle")
.attr("id","sugarDots")
.attr("r", 3.5)
.style("fill", "#9bcf81")
.attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d.date); })
.attr("cy", function(d) { return y(d.sum_nf_sugars); });

graph.selectAll("dot")
.data(data)
.enter().append("circle")
.attr("r", 3.5)
.style("fill", "#efa465")
.attr("id","carbDots")
.attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d.date); })
.attr("cy", function(d) { return y(d.sum_nf_total_carbohydrate); });


// Add the X Axis
graph.append("g")
.attr("class", "x axis")
.attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
.call(xAxis);

// Add the Y Axis
graph.append("g")
.attr("class", "y axis")
.call(yAxis);

//Add the Tic title
graph.append("text")
.attr("x", 15)             
.attr("y", 0)    
.attr("class", "legend")
.attr("id", "ticText")
.style("color", "#891f83")
.style("fill", "#891f83") 
.style("cursor", "pointer")
.style("font-family", "cooperbook")        
.on("click", function(){
        // Determine if current line is visible
        var active   = ticLine.active ? false : true,
        newOpacity = active ? 0 : 1;
        // Hide or show the elements
        width = 200;
        height = 200;
        d3.select("#ticLine").style("opacity", newOpacity);
        d3.selectAll("#ticDots").style("opacity", newOpacity);

        // Update whether or not the elements are active
        ticLine.active = active;
    })
.text("Tic Severity");

//Add the fatigue title
graph.append("text")
.attr("x", 115)             
.attr("y", 0)    
.attr("class", "legend")
.style("color", "#7bd6e3")
.style("fill", "#7bd6e3")
.style("cursor", "pointer")
.style("font-family", "cooperbook")
.on("click", function(){
        // Determine if current line is visible
        var active   = fatigueLine.active ? false : true,
        newOpacity = active ? 0 : 1;
        // Hide or show the elements
        d3.select("#fatigueLine").style("opacity", newOpacity);
        d3.selectAll("#fatigueDots").style("opacity", newOpacity);
        // Update whether or not the elements are active
        fatigueLine.active = active;
    })
.text("Fatigue");


//Add the Stress title
graph.append("text")
.attr("x", 190)             
.attr("y", 0)    
.attr("class", "legend")
.style("color", "#36376a")
.style("fill", "#36376a")
.style("cursor", "pointer")
.style("font-family", "cooperbook")          
.on("click", function(){
        // Determine if current line is visible
        var active   = stressLine.active ? false : true,
        newOpacity = active ? 0 : 1;
        // Hide or show the elements
        d3.select("#stressLine").style("opacity", newOpacity);
        d3.selectAll("#stressDots").style("opacity", newOpacity);
        // Update whether or not the elements are active
        stressLine.active = active;
    })
.text("Stress");

//Add the sugar title
graph.append("text")
.attr("x", 250)             
.attr("y", 0)    
.attr("class", "legend")
.style("color", "#9bcf81")
.style("fill", "#9bcf81")
.style("cursor", "pointer")
.style("font-family", "cooperbook")          
.on("click", function(){
        // Determine if current line is visible
        var active   = sugarLine.active ? false : true,
        newOpacity = active ? 0 : 1;
        // Hide or show the elements
        d3.select("#sugarLine").style("opacity", newOpacity);
        d3.selectAll("#sugarDots").style("opacity", newOpacity);
        // Update whether or not the elements are active
        sugarLine.active = active;
    })
.text("Sugars");

//Add the carb title
graph.append("text")
.attr("x", 320)             
.attr("y", 0)    
.attr("class", "legend")
.style("color", "#efa465")
.style("fill", "#efa465")
.style("cursor", "pointer")
.style("font-family", "cooperbook")          
.on("click", function(){
        // Determine if current line is visible
        var active   = carbLine.active ? false : true,
        newOpacity = active ? 0 : 1;
        // Hide or show the elements
        d3.select("#carbLine").style("opacity", newOpacity);
        d3.selectAll("#carbDots").style("opacity", newOpacity);
        // Update whether or not the elements are active
        carbLine.active = active;
    })
.text("Carbohydrates");
});



function resize() {
/* Find the new window dimensions */
var width = parseInt(d3.select("#graph").style("width")) - margin*2,
height = parseInt(d3.select("#graph").style("height")) - margin*2;

/* Update the range of the scale with new width/height */
x.range([0, width]).nice(d3.time.year);
y.range([height, 0]).nice();

/* Update the axis with the new scale */
graph.select('.x.axis')
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(xAxis);

graph.select('.y.axis')
  .call(yAxis);

/* Force D3 to recalculate and update the line */
graph.selectAll('.line')
  .attr("d", valueline(data));
}


d3.select(window).on('resize', resize);
```

Comment: Ever figure this out?